# Salesforce1 page responsive design

Tags: salesforce1-app

Hi how do you make the page only load data as you scroll down on the page? I don't want to load full data? Should I use paging via standardsetcontroller for instance?

Answer (score 2):

Visualforce is incredibly slow and clunky, especially for Salesforce1/mobile apps. Instead, I would strongly consider using the REST API to dynamically load more records as the user scrolls near the bottom of the page, or, even better, have a "... load more ..." button so they have control over if more data is loaded. You'll save a ton on bandwidth for your users and give them a better UX.

Comment: Yes I'm using remoteAction to populate data. How do I load data as I swipe the page like how Salesforce1 loads the page?

Comment: Basically, when you detect a swipe, simply call your remote action function and render the results when done. I'll see if I can find some code for you.